# How to translate the whole page?

Tags: localization

Ok so I know this is something really basic but unfortunately i could not find it in the documentation and I don't have a lot of experience with localisation at all. i have set up two locales in my craft admin panel and I have also updated general.php, etc to set up content localisation. But unfortunately the content that i set as translatable is still displayed in english at both the en and zh site post-fixes. Can somebody simply explain how can I use a link to change the language of all my content on a page to another language inside of a template?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have separate `index.php` files for your locales? There is a nicely explained documentation for this on the official Get Help pages: ["How do I show localized content on the front end?"](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/localization)